# Connected sortable lists with disabled items

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I use [this](http://farhadi.ir/projects/html5sortable/) shortable list, and I would like to use two connected sortable lists with disabled items.

Unfortunatelly it doesn't work.
Can anyone help me?

```
<section>
    <h1>Connected Sortable Lists</h1>
    <ul id="sortable4" class="connected sortable list">
        <li>Item 1
        <li>Item 2

    </ul>
    <ul id="sortable5" class="connected sortable list">
        <li class="disabled">Item 21
        <li class="highlight">Item 22

    </ul>
</section>

<script>
    $(function() {      
        $('#sortable5').sortable({
            items: ':not(.disabled)'
        });

        $('#sortable4, #sortable5').sortable({
            connectWith: '.connected'
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: What does not work? And what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Have you tried to include `items: ':not(.disabled)'` into the second sortable function call?

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comment above, I believe you need to have just one `sortable` function. So it probably should work as such:

```
<script>
    $(function() {      
        $('#sortable4, #sortable5').sortable({
            connectWith: '.connected',
            items: ':not(.disabled)'
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It works!
Unfortunatelly, I have another sortable function. Is it possible to do only one?

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
$('ul.sortable').sortable().bind(
    'sortupdate', function() {                      
        var dataIDList = $('ul.sortable li').map(
            function(){ 
                return $(this).attr("data-id");
            }
        ).get().join(",");

        $.post(
            'sort_save.php',{ idlist: dataIDList }, function(data){
                alert('ok!' + data); 
            }
        );
    }
);      

$(function() {      
    $('#sortable4, #sortable5').sortable({
        connectWith: '.connected',
        items: ':not(.disabled)'
    });
}); </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use two functions, you can define them as follows

```
$('#sortable4').sortable({
        connectWith: '#sortable5',
        items: ':not(.disabled)'
    });

$('#sortable5').sortable({
        connectWith: '#sortable4',
        items: ':not(.disabled)'
    });
```